# Absolute element width 100% ignoring padding content-box

Tags: html, css

I have an absolute element inside a relative container. The absolute element has its `width:100%` which gives the width of the relative container element.

My goal is for the absolute element to stretch beyond the 100% of the container, 40px from right and left.

This I am trying to achieve by setting `pading left & right to 40px` on the relative container, together with `box-sizing: content-box;`. The problem is that the absolute element doesn't stretch to 100% of the relative container. Instead it stretches only within the content space without including the padding.

**Edit**
Turns out that this is only in Chrome.

Comment: please provide fiddle what have you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jQuery here to calculate the width of DIV with paddings. Basically we need to apply the .`outerWidth()` of DIV to the table -

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/GDU7Q/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

just add `width:132%;` and `left:0px;`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HBGTt/)

Comment: Wrong answer, read the OP again. I need the table to stretch over the padded area.

Comment: @RegisteredUser now see my answer

Comment: width:132% is not good. I need for it to be fixed 40px.

Comment: @RegisteredUser check out the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

If you set your padding to 40px for each side it wants to believe the start of the absolute div is from the left of your relative div, you need to set a negative margin

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>

.outer {
    position:relative;
}

.inner {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    padding:0 40px;
    margin-left:-40px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dQuD4/11/)

Comment: Your fiddle example doesn't work as expected

Comment: Can you please explain your request a little more in depth then, as far as I was aware you wanted to stretch your absolute div 40 px either side of your relative div, which is what my fiddle showed. Does it need to be done with a table? Do you need to use the box-sizing styles?

Comment: Yes the table must remain. This is just a simplified example of much more complex HTML. I need the table to stretch to 100% of the blue box, over the right & left padded ends: http://jsfiddle.net/dQuD4/

Comment: I have just found out that the jsfiddle demo works in Chrome only.